# How to make query with condition for case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Right now I have this table in my DB:

```
table_book :
id (int),
author (varchar (50) ),
genre (varchar (50) ),
date (date),
country (varchar (50).
```

I wan't to make query like this:

```
select * from table_book 
case when date = null then select author
case when date > 1999-01-01 then select country
```

On first condition I would like get only author, on second condition I would like get only country (not all infos from table)

It's pretty simple example for query but I want to know how to do it on this way or it's impossible)

Comment: Any problem in that query ?

Comment: @AravindAravind it's didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a result based on that condition than

```
select 
(case 
when date Is Null then author
when date > Convert(datetime, '1999-01-01' ) then country
else ''
end) as res
from table_book
```

Comment: It's didn't work

Comment: did you get any error? @jimbo

Comment: you might need to cast author and country to same datatype if their datatype is different

Comment: @JayPatel
Data conversion error converting "A"; SQL statement:
select
(case

Comment: i think we get conversion error for date, i have updated answer

Comment: @JayPatel its not working and for int values also

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

select
(case
when date Is Null then cast(author as varchar)
when date > '1999-01-01' then cast(country as varchar)
else ''
end) as res
from table_book